# MySQL Workbench editor highlighted text color

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm on Windows 10 and I have been unable to figure out how to change the text color in MySQL Workbench when the **text is highlighted**.

[image]

I'm happy with all my other text and background colors in the `code_editor.xml` file (which I have just spent two hours customizing to resemble SQL Server Management Studio colors):

```
<style id= "0" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color="#008000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color="#008000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color="#0000FF" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color="#0000FF" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#C04000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#FF0000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#FF0000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#C040C0" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->

<!-- These two are for scintilla globally. -->
<style id="32" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!! -->
<style id="33" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#DDDDDD" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color="#FF8080" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color="#AAAAAA" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

It's so incredibly tedious in workbench to experiment by changing 1 color code, save, close Workbench, re-open workbench, open a connection, view a SQL/text file, evaluate colors...after each change. Which style element/attribute needs to be changed to affect the text color when that text is highlighted?

I'd be happy learning *either* how to change the text color when highlighted *or* the highlight color itself. Either one is fine, as long as it's high-contrast and easy to read. Note: When highlighting a green comment, it's truly impossible to read the text; the contrast is non-existent.

Note: I have posted this question already in Super User and on MySQL forum and received no helpful answers.

Comment: Change them all at the same time.  Based on the labels, it may not be *any* of them.

Comment: Which OS? If windows then I'm not sure it's possible except by changing windows' own colour scheme

Comment: Which Workbench version is that? Try the latest 8.0 RC where the selected text color is retrieved from the system instead of keeping the syntax colors. Since the background color is also a system color, these both should fit well together then.

Comment: Mike: Upgrading to Workbench 8.0 RC SOLVED my issue. Now, when editor text is highlighted, the text changes to WHITE, which is always easy to read. Can you post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to solve your issue is to upgrade to a newer Workbench version (8.0.11 RC is the current one), which has been changed to use the system's text selection color for selected text, instead of staying with the syntax highlighting colors.

Comment: Upgrading to 8.0 RC, in conjunction with my customized `code_editor.xml` shown above, solved the problem for me.